# LANG and LANGUAGE environment variable in Debian based systems

Tags: linux, debian, environment-variables, gnu, locale

It seems both the LANG and LANGUAGE environment variable are used by some programs to determine their user interface language.

What are the exact semantics of these variables and where can I read about their correct usage? The manpage for locale(1) only mentions the LC_* family of environment variables. Additionally there is also an LC_ALL variable commonly in place which isn't described there either.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**`LANG`** contain the setting for all categories that are not directly set by a `LC_*` variable.

**`LC_ALL`** is used to override every `LC_*` and `LANG` and `LANGUAGE`. It should not be set in a normal user environment, but can be useful when you are writing a script that depend on the precise output of an internationalized command.

**`LANGUAGE`** is used to set messages languages (as `LC_MESSAGES`) to a multi-valued value, e.g., setting it to `fr:de:en` will use French messages where they exist; if not, it will use German messages, and will fall back to English if  neither German nor French messages are available.

Comment: Where can I find documentation about LANGUAGE? Is it mutually exclusive to LC_MESSAGES?

Comment: Everything is in the locale(7) manpage.      LC_MESSAGES
          changes the language messages are displayed in and what
          an affirmative or negative  answer looks like.  The GNU
          C-library  contains  the gettext(3),  ngettext(3),  and
          rpmatch(3)  functions   to  ease   the  use   of  these
          information.  The GNU gettext  family of functions also
          obey  the environment  variable LANGUAGE  (containing a
          colon-separated list of locales) if the category is set
          to a valid locale other than "C".

Comment: @Rémi can you elaborate on why `LC_ALL` should not be used?

Comment: Not much to say. You have more flexibility if you set LANG than if you set LC_ALL: you can set LANG to something and LC_COLLATE to some other thing. If you set LC_ALL, every other configuration are hidden.

Comment: I don't think `LC_ALL` overrides `LANGUAGE`:
1. they have different meanings (order [e.g.: fr:de:en] vs. characteristics[e.g.: fr_FR])

Comment: 2. The GNU getText documentation's chapter [Specifying a Priority List of Languages](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable) states: `gettext gives preference to LANGUAGE over LC_ALL and LANG`. Additionally, the chapter [Locale Environment Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html#Locale-Environment-Variables) states: `1. LANGUAGE 2. LC_ALL [...]`

Comment: $LANGUAGE is not part of the C locales, but specific to GNU gettext. If set it is given precedence over anything else. I'm using it my own applications to avoid mixed languages when using gettext based libraries.

Comment: @Bachsau @Murmel  Clarifying point: that GNU getText documentation states the LANGUAGE is given precedence over LC_ALL and LANG `for the purpose of message handling`, and then only if LANG (or LC_ALL) is set to something other than 'C'.

Comment: @SpinUp Of course, because `C` is the fallback used when no `LC_*` or `LANG` variables are set. It disables all handling of locales and encoding, using only raw binary data. Even if `LANGUAGE` is set, gettext still uses the current locale to determine encoding. If there is none, there's nothing to encode to.

Comment: @Bachsau The most important point which is not clear in your comment or the one above it is that LANGUAGE **only overrides LC_MESSAGES**, having no effect on the other LC* variables.

Comment: @SpinUp Regarding your `LC_MESSAGES` comment, I thought that to be self-explaining, as gettext is only engaged in handling messages.

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at the manpage `locale(7)`: it describes that `LANG` is a fallback setting,  while `LC_ALL` overrides all separate `LC_*` settings.

Comment: man 7 locale is the command

Answer (score 5):

For reference, the locale system is GNU GetText, which has its full documentation available in the gettext-doc package (Debian/Ubuntu).

Alternatively, there is an online manual with authoritative and elaborate documentation of the  [LANG](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html#Locale-Environment-Variables) and [LANGUAGE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable) environment variables.

Comment: `gettext` is a library to localize messages, but it is not the whole locale system. The `LC_*` variables are used by several different parts of the C standard library and various other libraries as well.

Answer (score 0):

This answer attempts to directly quote relevant standards and contains no speculation or inaccurate statements. Edits and corrections welcome as long as they cite relevant standards and authoritative sources.

##### Environment Variable Priority

The priority of all four variables `LC_ALL`, `LC_*`, `LANG`, and `LANGUAGE` according to applicable standards:

1. `man 7 local`:

> If the second argument to setlocale(3) is an empty string, "", for  the
> default locale, it is determined using the following steps:
>
> 1. If  there  is  a  non-null environment variable LC_ALL, the value of
>    LC_ALL is used.
> 2. If an environment variable with the same name as one  of  the
>    categories above exists and is non-null, its value is used for
>    that category.
> 3. If there is a non-null environment variable LANG, the value of  LANG
>    is used.

2. [Gnu Gettext Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html#Locale-Environment-Variables%5D):

> When a program looks up locale dependent values, it does this according to the following environment variables, in priority order:
>
> 1. LANGUAGE
> 2. LC_ALL
> 3. LC_xxx, according to selected locale category: LC_CTYPE, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME, LC_COLLATE, LC_MONETARY, LC_MESSAGES, ...
> 4. LANG

So the currently accepted answer is inaccurate.

##### Environment Variable Format

From another part of the [Gnu Gettext Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Names.html):

> A locale name usually has the form ‘ll_CC’. Here ‘ll’ is an ISO 639 two-letter language code, and ‘CC’ is an ISO 3166 two-letter country code.

> Many locale names have an extended syntax ‘ll_CC.encoding’ that also specifies the character encoding.

> Some locale names use ‘ll_CC@variant’ instead of ‘ll_CC’. The ‘@variant’ can denote any kind of characteristics that is not already implied by the language ll and the country CC.